# Obtaining component elementId in parent template

Tags: ember.js

I would like to obtain component auto-generated `elementId` in parent template, e.g.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  my-component elementId: {{myComponentElementId}}
  {{my-component}}
</script>
```

Is there a simple way to do this without altering parent controller or `my-component`?

Comment: I tried binding `my-component` `elementId` property to underlying controller property,

    {{my-component elementId=myComponentElementId}}

however it fails with 

`You must use Ember.set() to set the elementId property (of <Ember.Component:ember294>) to ember294.`

See [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kareva/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access `elementId` by:

- explicitly naming component using its `viewName` attribute
- accessing component by its name from parent template `view.[componentName].elementId`

Example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  my-component elementId: {{view.myComponent.elementId}}
  {{my-component viewName="myComponent"}}
</script>
```

[JsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kareva/2/)

**NOTE**

With introduction of Glimmer rendering engine (Ember version **>=1.13**), accessing `elementId` via `viewName` is [not supported any more](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11156#issuecomment-102896935).

Instead, component's `elementId` should be explicitly set to specific value, e.g.

Example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  my-component elementId: index-my-component
  {{my-component id="index-my-component"}}
</script>
```

In this case, it is up to developer to make sure that `elementId` is unique within page DOM. If template is to be rendered multiple times, `elementId` should be concatenated from parent component `elementId` and some predefined id (see [JsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rwjblue/511/edit?html,js,output))

Comment: Note that this does not work on current beta version of Ember (Glimmer version) - not sure whether my solution is using unsupported private API or it is a bug in ember 1.13

Comment: I have created a related [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11188)...

Answer (score 1):

`elementId` is being generated during initialization of the component. You can be sure that the ID is set after the component is fully inserted into DOM. Therefore, you can use `didInsertElement` action like this:

```
some-example elementId: {{myComponentElementId}}
{{some-example elementIdProxy=myComponentElementId}}

didInsertElement: function() {
  this.set("elementIdProxy", this.get("elementId"));
}
```

Thus, you proxy the `elementId` via some other binding (`elementIdProxy` in this situation). I strongly recommend not to set up the ID explicitly, as it must be unique within the app. Ember takes care about that, so it's not a good idea to reinvent the wheel.

[Fully working example in JSBin is here](http://jsbin.com/lizino/4/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This is how i would do it. However Using ElementID and storing it somewhere to later recognize the element is not a good solution. On each re-route the id changes. E.g  R1(ember123) > R2(ember234 > R1 (ember312) even the R1 changes.

Comment: Absolutly agree. I would even say that if there is any reason you have to get `elementId`, there is a very huge probability that you do something wrong. It is fully ember private and should not be needed. However, if you really need it, I think that this is a good solution.

Comment: This solution does indeed work; however I would like to avoid extending components for which I need `elementId`. In my use case I have to get `elementId` for various components, many of them imported from addons...

Comment: Some background on why I need `elementId`: I need to provide label for components, i.e. `<label for={{elementIdOfComponent}}>{{component}}`

Comment: Nevertheless, if you need accessing private property and must do an effort to do this, think about other ways. `label` can be bound to the element also by inserting an element inside the `label`. Look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: every time something looks odd in ember, means you're doing it wrong =D

Answer (score 0):

In your bin you are trying to pass an id but not specified the value on the controller. Set the id value in the `setupCotroller` hook on the controller and that value will be used as the id.

Otherwise you will need to pass the id up via actions. [Here is the link.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dasepo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

The problem (ie the source of your error message) is you're trying to override the component's `elementId` property via attribute binding. I have run into this issue when trying to pass in `id`. A simple work around is to use `_elementId` or any other word that isn't `elementId`.  Check the [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sohuxiqadi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)